# I keep getting the error message in python TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python

I have been creating a cipher and I have been getting an error message:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

my code currently is:

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
key = 5
cipher = ' ' 

choice = input('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt? E/D')
if not choice == 'D' and not choice == 'E':
    raise Exception('Must enter E or D for Encrypt or Decrypt')
user_input = input('Please enter your word')
cipher2 = cipher (user_input, alphabet, choice, key)
print('your encrypted mesaage 2 is: ' + cipher2)

#Method can encrypt or decrypt the entered word
def cipher(plain_text, alphabet, choice, key):
    cipher = ''
    for c in plain_text:
        if c in alphabet:
            if choice == 'E':
                val1 = alphabet.index(c)
                val2 = key
                cipher += alphabet[ (val1 + val2) % (len(alphabet))]
            elif choice == 'D':
                cipher = cipher + alphabet[ (alphabet.index(c)-key) % (len(alphabet))]
return cipher
```

the error is on line nine :

```
    cipher2 = cipher (user_input, alphabet, choice, key)
```

Appreciate the help if anyone can

Comment: You have a variable called `cipher` defined in your 3rd line.

Answer (score 3):

Your string `cipher`(defiend in line 3) have same name as your function `cipher` :

```
print (type(cipher)) #  class <'str'>

cipher2 = cipher (user_input, alphabet, choice, key) # cipher is string here not function
```

when you call this check `cipher` type it's `string` so change your string name or function name.